# Unable to get my GTX1060 to work on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial - help!

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, surface

I have a Surface Book 2 with:
i7-8565U
16 GB RAM
Intel UHD 620 Graphics
Nvidia GTX1060 Graphics 
I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 for programming on ROS using Gazebo and RViz.

I noticed that I was getting 6 fps in Husky RViz with Gazebo open as well.
I checked and my Powermizer settings and it is locked to performance level 0 NO MATTER WHAT!

I looked into countless answers here and on google and tried all the fixes using xorg.conf and adding coolbits etc, but the GPU remained at performance level 0.
I then activated the nouveau display driver and uninstalled the nvidia driver(tried many driver versions with same results) and the fps rose up to 30.

However, I wanted to check which GPU was being used and I found that it was the Intel GPU!
I will attach whatever tests I ran as well.

How do I resolve this so that the system can use the dGPU when under load and the Intel HD when browsing etc, should I use nvidia drivers or nouveau and if it is nouveau how do I fix it? 
Thank you!

[image: Terminal test-1]

[image: Terminal test-2]

Comment: is there nvidea module loaded? did you install the nvidea driver? I red this may could help: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I installed many versions, tried. various recommended ways to get it active,including more extreme measures such as xorg config files, etc as the method you linked just did not seem to work many times over, after this post I reinstalled ubuntu and tried to install nvidia driver again but no luck..